# Diagnose Memory Graph

Tags: linux, memory-usage, swap

The monitoring software we use has been flagged a box that serves two apps:

- Confluence (xms: 1 GB, xmx: 2 GB)
- JIRA (xms: 1 GB, xmx: 1 GB)

These are the only two applications on the box; nothing else but it is a VM.

Server Config

- VM (VMWare)
- RedHat EL 5
- 2 GB memory allocated

### The Graph

[image]
What's really weird to me is that peak times should be between 8 AM and 5 PM, but on Thursday morning, from 1 AM to 8 AM.  Not as bad, but Friday is similar--swap is being used though there's no load I'd expect at that time.

Help?

Comment: Our servers fetch and apply updates via cron-apt during the wee hours (4AM).  Anything like that going on?

Comment: @nedm: Not applicable to us, as far as I know.  Last I heard, the VM hasn't been patched in months.  I don't think it's been in use for 9 months yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run atop in daemon mode:

```
atop -a -w /var/log/atop.log 600
```

let it log for the night, read the log afterwards with

```
atop -r /var/log/atop.log
```

you can scroll forward and backward with `t` and `T`, memory details are shown after pressing `m`

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  We determined that the applications were delegated more RAM than the system had, so it was increased and things are fine now--no more memory/swap warnings.